# NSIS installer like loader

Tags: nsis

For my project i need to do next:

1. Install Silverlight
2. Install XAP file
3. Run XAP file

It takes only 3 minutes, no configuration, just click-and-install

I would like to hide all controlls (progress bar, buttons, log list). Just logo and gif loading animation. All steps to create installer was done, so now i need to know could i do such customization or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create simple NSIS installer with SILENT flag.

Use Exec to execute Silverlight and XAP installation (also in quiet mode) and filanne use ShellExecute to open a XAP file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want to hide silverlight's buttons or your one.

Silverlight: try quiet mode: **/q**.

Your: that long story, we need your NSIS code first.